# Trying passing object with savedStateHandle and Parcelable in Jetpack compose and navgraph

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

I working on change my app from xml to copose and getting stuck, I am trying to get an object using savedStateHandle but I didn't recrvied any data, all is null alwas!

my **Data class**

```
    @Parcelize
data class TodoUI(
    val id: Long = 0,
    val title: String = "",
    val isCompleted: Boolean = false,
) : Parcelable
```

here's my **TodoDetailsArgs**

```
class TodoDetailsArgs(savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle) {

val todo = savedStateHandle.get<TodoUI>(TODO_DETAIL)

companion object {
    const val TODO_DETAIL = "todo"
   }
}
```

my **TodoEditRoute**

```
    fun NavGraphBuilder.todoEditRoute(navController: NavController) {
    dialog(
        route = Screen.TodoEdit.route,
    ) {
        val todo = navController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.get<TodoUI>(TodoDetailsArgs.TODO_DETAIL)
        Log.d("TodoEditRoute", "todo: $todo")
        TodoEditScreen(
            navController = navController,
            onDismiss = { navController.popBackStack() }
        )
    }
}

fun NavController.navigateToEditTodo(todo: TodoUI) {
    val todo2 = currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(TodoDetailsArgs.TODO_DETAIL, todo)
    Log.d("TodoEditRoute", "todo2: $todo2")
    navigate(Screen.TodoEdit.route)
}
```

and here's how I revice it in my viewmodel

```
@HiltViewModel
class TodoEditingViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val updateTodoTitleUseCase: UpdateTodoTitleUseCase,
    private val deleteTodoUseCase: DeleteTodoUseCase,
    state: SavedStateHandle,
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _todoArgs = TodoDetailsArgs(state)

    private val todo = MutableStateFlow(TodoUI())
    val todoTitle = MutableStateFlow("")

    init {
        initNavArgs()
    }

    private fun initNavArgs() {
        todo.value = _todoArgs.todo ?: TodoUI()
        todoTitle.value = todo.value.title
        Log.d("TodoEditRoute", "todo3: ${todo.value}")
    }
```

and finally my log when I long click on todo item with id (7)!!

```
todo2: kotlin.Unit
todo: TodoUI(id=7, title=hi, isCompleted=false)
todo3: TodoUI(id=0, title=, isCompleted=false)
todo: TodoUI(id=7, title=hi, isCompleted=false)
```

Comment: any help devs.?